# awk to compare two files

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to compare two files and want to print the matching lines... The lines present in the files will be unique

**File1.txt**

```
GERMANY
FRANCE
UK
POLLAND
```

**File2.txt**

```
POLLAND 
GERMANY
```

I tried with below command

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="\n" } ; NR==FNR{A[$1]++;NEXT}A[$1]' File1.txt File2.txt
```

but it is printing the matching record twice, I want them to be printed once...

**UPDATE**

expected output

```
POLLAND 
GERMANY
```

Current Output

```
POLLAND 
GERMANY
POLLAND 
GERMANY
```

Comment: See also: [Fastest way to find lines of a file from another larger file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-file-from-another-larger-file-in-bash).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`grep` together with `-f` (for file) is best for this:

```
$ grep -f f1 f2
POLLAND 
GERMANY
```

And in fact, to get exact matches and no regex, use respectively `-w` and `-F`:

```
$ grep -wFf f1 f2
POLLAND 
GERMANY
```

---

If you really have to do it with `awk`, then you can use:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a' f1 f2
POLLAND 
GERMANY
```

- `FNR==NR` is performed when reading the first file.
- `{a[$1]; next}` stores in `a[]` the lines of the first file and goes to the next line.
- `$1 in a` is evaluated when looping through the second file. It checks if the current line is within the `a[]` array.

---

#### Why wasn't your script working?

- Because you used `NEXT` instead of `next`. So it was treated as a constant instead of a command.
- Also, because the `BEGIN { FS="\n" }` was wrong, as the default `FS` is a space and it is ok to be like that. Setting it as a new line was making it misbehave.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,due to requirement  i wanted them using `awk` command

Comment: Perfect Got it, New to awk, your information is very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Your command should maybe be:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]++;next}A[$1]' file1 file2
```

You have a stray semi-colon after the closing brace of BEGIN{} and also have "NEXT" in capital letters and have mis-spelled your filename.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{name[$1]++;next}$1 in name' file1.txt file2.txt
```

- You iterate through first file `NR==FNR` storing the names in an array called `names`.
- You use `next` to prevent the second action from happneing until first file is completely stored in array.
- Once the first file is complete, you start the next file by checking if it is present in the array. It will print out the name if it exits.
- `FS` is field separator. You don't need to set that to `new line`. You need `RS` which is `Record Separator` to be new line. But we don't do that here because that it the default value.

Comment: +1 thanks it works, Can you please add some explanation to your code and explain why mine is failing

Answer (score 0):

If you don't *have* to use awk, a better alternative might be the GNU coreutil, `comm`. From the man page:

```
comm -12 file1 file2 Print only lines present in both file1 and file2.
```