# Fastest way to find lines of a file from another larger file in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, grep

I have two files, `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`.  `file1.txt` has about 14K lines and `file2.txt` has about 2 billions.  `file1.txt` has a single field `f1` per line while `file2.txt` has 3 fields, `f1` through `f3`, delimited by `|`.

I want to find all lines from `file2.txt` where `f1` of `file1.txt` matches `f2` of `file2.txt` (or anywhere on the line if we don't want to spend extra time splitting the values of `file2.txt`).

file1.txt (about 14K lines, **not sorted**):

```
foo1
foo2
...
bar1
bar2
...
```

file2.txt (about 2 billion lines, **not sorted**):

```
date1|foo1|number1
date2|foo2|number2
...
date1|bar1|number1
date2|bar2|number2
...
```

Output expected:

```
date1|foo1|number1
date2|foo2|number2
...
date1|bar1|number1
date2|bar2|number2
...
```

Here is what I have tried and it seems to be taking several hours to run:

```
fgrep -F -f file1.txt file2.txt > file.matched
```

I wonder if there is a better and faster way of doing this operation with the common Unix commands or with a small script.

Comment: You could let us know the timing of the below solutions on your actual input.

Comment: @Inian - I will definitely do that.  Waiting for more answers.

Comment: Updated my answer for matching anywhere in the line, but I am guessing it is going to be tad slower when matching in `$2` alone.

Comment: I would be not shocked, but somewhat surprised, if you found something significantly faster than `fgrep` for this task. A two-billion-line text file is not going to be fast to process no matter what..

Comment: Are the data somehow ordered? are `C`-based solutions available?

Comment: See accepted solution for [Fastest possible grep](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9066609/2800918)

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. - the data is not ordered.  Just updated the question.

Comment: how many cores/cpus does the machine you're running this on have? And, are you open to running this search on multiple servers?

Comment: @gregory - this is for my work laptop - MBP with a single CPU and 4 cores.  Multiple servers not preferred.

Comment: If you want to benchmark the solutions, it will be necessary to drop the file system cache to fairly compare.  See, e.g. [this](https://linux-mm.org/Drop_Caches).

Comment: I am a little bit confused. You say that you can match either field no 2 exactly or anywhere on the line, but then the first solution (matching exactly field no 2) is clearly more restrictive in general. For example, given the word `foo1`, the first solution will **not** match `foo1|date|number1`, whereas the second solution (match anywhere on the line) will accept this as a match. So which method are you actually going to use for your problem?

Comment: @HåkonHægland - I should have stated it more clearly - yes, I do need to match the second field, not the entire line.  It especially make sense for the hash based solution.

Comment: @codeforester It would be nice if you could upload `file1.txt` to for example [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and provide a link to the file. Then we could try to test codes on at least some real data :)

Comment: @codeforester please make up your mind and edit your question to state clearly if you want to match the f1 value in just the 2nd field of f2 or anywhere in the line in f2. Don't say "I'd like X but Y would be OK too" - just state your requirement, X or Y. Also state if a partial match is considered a match ( e.g. does `foo` in f1 match `foobar` in f2?) and if you're looking for a regexp or string match (e.g. does `f.*r` in f1 match `foobar` in f2?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A small piece of Perl code solved the problem.  This is the approach taken:

- store the lines of `file1.txt` in a hash
- read `file2.txt` line by line, parse and extract the second field
- check if the extracted field is in the hash; if so, print the line

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
if (scalar(@ARGV) != 2) {
  printf STDERR "Usage: fgrep.pl smallfile bigfile\n";
  exit(2);
}

my ($small_file, $big_file) = ($ARGV[0], $ARGV[1]);
my ($small_fp, $big_fp, %small_hash, $field);

open($small_fp, "<", $small_file) || die "Can't open $small_file: " . $!;
open($big_fp, "<", $big_file)     || die "Can't open $big_file: "   . $!;

# store contents of small file in a hash
while (<$small_fp>) {
  chomp;
  $small_hash{$_} = undef;
}
close($small_fp);

# loop through big file and find matches
while (<$big_fp>) {
  # no need for chomp
  $field = (split(/\|/, $_))[1];
  if (defined($field) && exists($small_hash{$field})) {
    printf("%s", $_);
  }
}

close($big_fp);
exit(0);
```

---

I ran the above script with 14K lines in file1.txt and 1.3M lines in file2.txt.  It finished in about 13 seconds, producing 126K matches.  Here is the `time` output for the same:

```
real    0m11.694s
user    0m11.507s
sys 0m0.174s
```

I ran @Inian's `awk` code:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{hash[$1]; next}{for (i in hash) if (match($0,i)) {print; break}}' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt
```

It was way slower than the Perl solution, since it is looping 14K times for each line in file2.txt - which is really expensive. It aborted after processing 592K records of `file2.txt` and producing 40K matched lines. Here is how long it took:

```
awk: illegal primary in regular expression 24/Nov/2016||592989 at 592989
 input record number 675280, file file2.txt
 source line number 1

real    55m5.539s
user    54m53.080s
sys 0m5.095s
```

Using @Inian's other `awk` solution, which eliminates the looping issue:

```
time awk -F '|' 'FNR==NR{hash[$1]; next}$2 in hash' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt > awk1.out

real    0m39.966s
user    0m37.916s
sys 0m0.743s

time LC_ALL=C awk -F '|' 'FNR==NR{hash[$1]; next}$2 in hash' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt > awk.out

real    0m41.057s
user    0m38.475s
sys 0m0.904s
```

`awk` is very impressive here, given that we didn't have to write an entire program to do it.

I ran @oliv's Python code as well.  It took about 15 hours to complete the job, and looked like it produced the right results.  Building a huge regex isn't as efficient as using a hash lookup.  Here the `time` output:

```
real    895m14.862s
user    806m59.219s
sys 1m12.147s
```

I tried to follow the suggestion to use [parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42309876/6862601).  However, it failed with `fgrep: memory exhausted` error, even with very small block sizes.

---

What surprised me was that `fgrep` was totally unsuitable for this.  I aborted it after 22 hours and it produced about 100K matches.  **I wish `fgrep` had an option to force the content of `-f file` to be kept in a hash, just like what the Perl code did.**

I didn't check `join` approach - I didn't want the additional overhead of sorting the files.  Also, given `fgrep`'s poor performance, I don't believe `join` would have done better than the Perl code.

Thanks everyone for your attention and responses.

Comment: Your "fgrep: memory exhausted" is surprising; I know you're using a MBP, so I assume you're using the BSD grep version.  Can you try gnu grep with the -F flag? (can be installed with homebrew and run with gfgrep).

Comment: I believe agrep uses a hash of the patterns when using -f.  You might want to give that a try; it too is installable using homebrew.

Comment: 1) `defined($field)` should be unnecessary. If it is necessary, consider just turning off "uninitialized" warnings instead. 2) `exists($small_hash{$field})` can be replaced with the (ever so slightly) faster `$small_hash{$field}` if you assigned `1` instead of `undef` as the hash values. 3) `printf("%s", $_);` is a slow version of `print;`.

Comment: I realized the mistake that I had not tested @Inian's optimized `awk` solution.  Just updated my answer to include that.

Answer (score 19):

A Perl solution.   [See **Note** below.]

Use a hash for the first file. As you read the big file line-by-line, extract the field by regex (captures the first pattern between `||`) or `split` (gets the second word) and print if it `exists`. They likely differ in speed a bit (time them). The `defined` check isn't needed in the regex while for `split` use `//` (defined-or) that short-circuits.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

# If 'prog smallfile bigfile' is the preferred use
die "Usage: $0 smallfile bigfile\n"  if @ARGV != 2;
my ($smallfile, $bigfile) = @ARGV;

open my $fh, '<', $smallfile or die "Can't open $smallfile: $!";    
my %word = map { chomp; $_ => 1 } <$fh>;

open    $fh, '<', $bigfile or die "Can't open $bigfile: $!";       
while (<$fh>) 
{
    exists $word{ (/\|([^|]+)/)[0] } && print;  

    # Or
    #exists $word{ (split /\|/)[1] // '' } && print;
}
close $fh;
```

Avoiding the `if` branch and using short-circuit is faster, but only very little. On billions of lines these tweaks add up but again not to too much. It may (or may not) be a tad bit faster to read the small file line by line, instead of in list context as above, but this should *not* be noticeable.

**Update**   Writing to `STDOUT` saves two operations and I repeatedly time it to be a little faster than writing to a file. Such usage is also consistent with most UNIX tools so I changed to write to `STDOUT`. Next, the `exists` test is not needed and dropping it spares an operation. However, I consistently get a touch better runtimes *with it*, while it also conveys the purpose better. Altogether I am leaving it in. Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for comments.

**Note**   The commented out version is **about 50% faster** than the other, by my benchmark below. These are both given because they are *different*, one finding the first match and the other the second field. I am keeping it this way as a more generic choice, since the question is ambiguous on that.

---

*Some comparisons (benchmark)    [Updated for writing to `STDOUT`, see "Update" above]*

There is an extensive analysis in the [answer by HåkonHægland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42370477/4653379), timing one run of most solutions. Here is another take, benchmarking the two solutions above, the OP's own answer, and the posted `fgrep` one, expected to be fast and used in the question and in many answers.

I build test data in the following way.  A handful of lines of the length roughly as shown are made with random words, for both files, so to match in the second field. Then I pad this "seed" for data samples with lines that won't match, so to mimic ratios between sizes and matches quoted by OP: for *14K* lines in small file there are *1.3M* lines in the big file, yielding *126K* matches. Then these samples are written repeatedly to build full data files as OP's,  [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html)::`shuffle`-ed each time.

All runs compared below produce `106_120` matches for the above file sizes (`diff`-ed for a check), so the matching frequency is close enough.
They are benchmarked by calling complete programs using `my $res = timethese(60 ...)`. The result of `cmpthese($res)` on v5.16 are

```
        Rate regex  cfor split fgrep
regex 1.05/s    --  -23%  -35%  -44%
cfor  1.36/s   30%    --  -16%  -28%
split 1.62/s   54%   19%    --  -14%
fgrep 1.89/s   80%   39%   17%    --
```

The fact that the optimized C-program `fgrep` comes on top isn't surprising. The lag of "*regex*" behind "*split*" may be due to the overhead of starting the engine for little matches, *many* times. This may vary over Perl versions, given the evolving regex engine optimizations. I include the answer of @codeforester ("*cfor*") since it was claimed to be fastest, and its `24%` lag behind the very similar "*split*" is likely due to scattered small inefficiencies (see a comment below this answer).<sup>†</sup>

This isn't shatteringly different, while there are sure variations across hardware and software and over data details. I ran this on different Perls and machines, and the notable difference is that *in some cases `fgrep` was indeed an order of magnitude faster*.

The OP's experience of very slow `fgrep` is surprising. Given their quoted run times, order of magnitude slower than the above, I'd guess that there's an old system to "blame."

Even though this is completely I/O based there are concurrency benefits from putting it on multiple cores and I'd expect a good speedup, up to a factor of a few.

---

<sup>†</sup> Alas, the comment got deleted (?). In short: unneeded use of a scalar (costs), of an `if` branch, of `defined`, of `printf` instead of `print` (slow!). These matter for runtime on 2 billion lines.

Comment: One less op if you change `exists $word{ (/\|([^|]+)/)[0] }` to `$word{ (/\|([^|]+)/)[0] }`. There's no reason not to print to STDOUT, which removes another two ops.

Comment: @ikegami  Thank you for comments -- they touch on things I wasn't sure about. (1) Without `exists` it fetches (and returns) the value. I thought that `exists` (somehow) avoids that (while it is one function call more)?  (2) Is there no overhead to printing 'out' and having shell redirect? I have compared (timed) these in the past and never found direct writes to file to be faster, but I don't understand it.

Comment: @ikegami  For whatever it's worth, complete comparison: 1.61/s (with `exists`, write to file), 1.62/s (with `exists`, write to stdout, best), 1.56/s (without `exists`, write to file), 1.57/s (without `exists`, write to stdout).  It appears (in this one benchmark on this system) that `exists` helps (a tiny bit) while the direct write is _slower_ than writing to stdout (I do _not_ understand this).

Comment: @zdim I updated my test-suite to include your last update using the short-curcuit `if` and printing to `STDOUT` instead of printing to the file, i.e. I used this: `exists $word{ (/\|([^|]+)/)[0] } && print`. However, there was practically no difference in the timings. For the small case in my answer I still got 0.61s run time, and for the large case the run time was still around 6.55s. Note, that the output from the script was still saved to file using shell redirection (`zdim.pl > out.txt`).

Comment: .. so I cannot see that using `zdim.pl` (without shell redirection) and
saving the output to `out.txt` *within* the script would be any
different (be more efficient).

Comment: @HåkonHægland  Thank you. No, that may not show much of a difference. What _does_ is uncommenting the line with `split` and commenting out the line with regex.  So to use `split`-based solution instead of the regex one (both are just one line :). That should give 50% speedup. (Btw, the short-circuit has been there all along, I never had an `if`.  That also helps only very little, possibly unnoticed. Also btw, previous to this change this script wasn't printing anything to `STDOUT`, but was writing out a separate file.)

Comment: @HåkonHægland  I am keeping the regex-based one as the "main" solution (while the other one is commented out) merely because it is not clear in the question whether OP wants _any_ match or the second field -- and finding _any_ match strikes me as more generic (so, regex).  I might as well just switch to have the faster code be the "main" solution.  All it takes is moving one `#` from one line to another.

Comment: @zdim Yes, you are right! Commenting out the `split` improved performance. I tested it now: Small case: 0.4s, large case: 4.21s, that is also clearly better than the Perl script of `codeforester`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Alright, that makes sense -- thank you! It has to be clearly better (but not by all that much), as explained in text. While the regex-based one does lag behind the `split`, I guess because starting the regex engine is a big overhead for the super-simple straight match that is needed, compared to straightforward and simple work that `split` does (break by space and pick one element to return).

Answer (score 17):

I have tried to do a comparison between some of the methods presented here.

First I created a Perl script to generate the input files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. In order to compare some of the solutions, I made sure that the the words from `file1.txt` only could appear in the second field in `file2.txt`. Also to be able to use the `join` solution presented by @GeorgeVasiliou, I sorted `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. Currently I generated the input files based on only 75 random words ( taken from https://www.randomlists.com/random-words ). Only 5 of these 75 words was used in `file1.txt` the remaining 70 words was used to fill up the fields in `file2.txt`. It might be necessary to increase the number of words substantially to get realistic results ( according to the OP, the original `file1.txt` contained 14000 words). In the tests below I used a `file2.txt` with 1000000 ( 1 million ) lines. The script also generates the file `regexp1.txt` required by the grep solution of @BOC.

**gen_input_files.pl**:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Printer;
use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions ("num_lines=i" => \my $nlines )
  or die("Error in command line arguments\n");

# Generated random words from site: https://www.randomlists.com/random-words
my $word_filename        = 'words.txt'; # 75 random words
my $num_match_words      = 5;
my $num_file2_lines      = $nlines || 1_000_000;
my $file2_words_per_line = 3;
my $file2_match_field_no = 2;
my $file1_filename       = 'file1.txt';
my $file2_filename       = 'file2.txt';
my $file1_regex_fn       = 'regexp1.txt';

say "generating $num_file2_lines lines..";
my ( $words1, $words2 ) = get_words( $word_filename, $num_match_words );

write_file1( $file1_filename, $words2 );
write_file2(
    $file2_filename, $words1, $words2, $num_file2_lines,
    $file2_words_per_line, $file2_match_field_no
);
write_BOC_regexp_file( $file1_regex_fn, $words2 );


sub write_BOC_regexp_file {
    my ( $fn, $words ) = @_;

    open( my $fh, '>', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    print $fh '\\|' . (join "|", @$words) . '\\|';
    close $fh;
}

sub write_file2 {
    my ( $fn, $words1, $words2, $nlines, $words_per_line, $field_no ) = @_;

    my $nwords1 = scalar @$words1;
    my $nwords2 = scalar @$words2;
    my @lines;
    for (1..$nlines) {
        my @words_line;
        my $key;
        for (1..$words_per_line) {
            my $word;
            if ( $_ != $field_no ) {
                my $index = int (rand $nwords1);
                $word = @{ $words1 }[$index];
            }
            else {
                my $index = int (rand($nwords1 + $nwords2) );
                if ( $index < $nwords2 ) {
                    $word = @{ $words2 }[$index];
                }
                else {
                    $word =  @{ $words1 }[$index - $nwords2];
                }
                $key = $word;
            }
            push @words_line, $word;
        }
        push @lines, [$key, (join "|", @words_line)];
    }
    @lines = map { $_->[1] } sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] } @lines; 
    open( my $fh, '>', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    print $fh (join "\n", @lines);
    close $fh;
}

sub write_file1 {
    my ( $fn, $words ) = @_;

    open( my $fh, '>', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    print $fh (join "\n", sort @$words);
    close $fh;
}

sub get_words {
    my ( $fn, $N ) = @_;

    open( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    my @words = map {chomp $_; $_} <$fh>;
    close $fh;

    my @words1 = @words[$N..$#words];
    my @words2 = @words[0..($N - 1)];
    return ( \@words1, \@words2 );
}
```

Next, I created a sub folder `solutions` with all the test cases:

```
$ tree solutions/
solutions/
├── BOC1
│   ├── out.txt
│   └── run.sh
├── BOC2
│   ├── out.txt
│   └── run.sh
├── codeforester
│   ├── out.txt
│   ├── run.pl
│   └── run.sh
[...]
```

Here the files `out.txt` is the output from the greps for each solution. The scripts `run.sh` runs the solution for the given test case.

### Notes on the different solutions

- **`BOC1`** : First solution presented by @BOC

  ```
  grep -E -f regexp1.txt file2.txt
  ```
- **`BOC2`** : Second solution suggested by @BOC:

  ```
  LC_ALL=C grep -E -f regexp1.txt file2.txt
  ```
- **`codeforester`** : Accepted Perl solution by @codeforester ( see [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42337557/2173773) )
- **`codeforester_orig`** : Original solution presented by @codeforested:

  ```
  fgrep -f file1.txt file2.txt
  ```
- **`dawg`** : Python solution using dictionary and split line proposed by @dawg ( see [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42426100/2173773) )
- **`gregory1`** : solution using Gnu Parallel suggested by @gregory

  ```
  parallel -k --pipepart -a file2.txt --block "$block_size" fgrep -F -f file1.txt
  ```

  See note below regarding how to choose `$block_size`.
- **`hakon1`** : Perl solution provided by @HåkonHægland (see [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42495367/2173773)). This solution requires compilation of the c-extension the first time the code is run. It does not require recompilation when `file1.txt` or `file2.txt` changes. Note: The time used to compile the c-extension at the initial run is not included in the run times presented below.
- **`ikegami`** : Solution using assembled regexp and using `grep -P` as given by @ikegami. Note: The assembled regexp was written to a separate file `regexp_ikegami.txt`, so the runtime of generating the regexp is not included in the comparison below. This is the code used:

  ```
  regexp=$(< "regexp_ikegami.txt")
  grep -P "$regexp" file2.txt
  ```
- **`inian1`** : First solution by @Inian using `match()`

  ```
  awk 'FNR==NR{
      hash[$1]; next
  }
  {
     for (i in hash) if (match($0,i)) {print; break}
  }' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt
  ```
- **`inian2`** : Second solution by @Inian using `index()`

  ```
  awk 'FNR==NR{
      hash[$1]; next
  }
  {
     for (i in hash) if (index($0,i)) {print; break}
  }' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt
  ```
- **`inian3`** : Third solution by @Inian checking only `$2` field:

  ```
  awk 'FNR==NR{
      hash[$1]; next
  }
  $2 in hash' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt
  ```
- **`inian4`** : 4th soultion by @Inian ( basically the same as `codeforester_orig` with `LC_ALL` ) :

  ```
  LC_ALL=C fgrep -f file1.txt file2.txt
  ```
- **`inian5`** : 5th solution by @Inian (same as `inian1` but with `LC_ALL` ):

  ```
  LC_ALL=C awk 'FNR==NR{
      hash[$1]; next
  }
  {
     for (i in hash) if (match($0,i)) {print; break}
  }' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt
  ```
- **`inian6`** : Same as `inian3` but with `LC_ALL=C`. Thanks to @GeorgeVasiliou for suggestion.
- **`jjoao`** : Compiled flex-generated C code as proposed by @JJoao (see [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42621587/2173773) ). Note: Recompilation of the exectuable must be done each time `file1.txt` changes. The time used to compile the executable is not included in the run times presented below.
- **`oliv`** : Python script provided by @oliv ( see [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42295002/2173773) )
- **`Vasiliou`** : Using `join` as suggested by @GeorgeVasiliou:

  ```
  join --nocheck-order -11 -22 -t'|' -o 2.1 2.2 2.3 file1.txt file2.txt
  ```
- **`Vasiliou2`** : Same as `Vasiliou` but with `LC_ALL=C`.
- **`zdim`** : Using Perl script provided by @zdim ( see [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42340329/2173773) ). Note: This uses the regexp search version ( instead of split line solution ).
- **`zdim2`** : Same as `zdim` except that it uses the `split` function instead of regexp search for the field in `file2.txt`.

#### Notes

1. I experimented a little bit with Gnu parallel (see `gregory1` solution above) to determine the optimal block size for my CPU. I have 4 cores, and and currently it seems that the optimal choice is to devide the file (`file2.txt`) into 4 equal sized chunks, and run a single job on each of the 4 processors. More testing might be needed here. So for the first test case where `file2.txt` is 20M, I set `$block_size` to 5M ( see `gregory1` solution above), whereas for the more realistic case presented below where `file2.txt` is 268M, a `$block_size` of 67M was used.
2. The solutions `BOC1`, `BOC2`, `codeforester_orig`, `inian1`, `inian4`, `inian5`, and `gregory1` all used loose matching. Meaning that the words from `file1.txt` did not have to match exactly in field #2 of `file2.txt`. A match anywhere on the line was accepted. Since this behavior made it more difficult to compare them with the other methods, some modified methods were also introduced. The first two methods called `BOC1B` and `BOC2B` used a modified `regexp1.txt` file. The lines in the original `regexp1.txt` where on the form `\|foo1|foo2|...|fooN\|` which would match the words at any field boundary. The modified file, `regexp1b.txt`, anchored the match to field #2 exclusively using the form `^[^|]*\|foo1|foo2|...|fooN\|` instead.

   Then the rest of the modified methods `codeforester_origB`, `inian1B`, `inian4B`, `inian5B`, and `gregory1B` used a modified `file1.txt`. Instead of a *literal* word per line, the modified file `file1b.txt` used one *regex* per line on the form:

   ```
    ^[^|]*\|word1\|
    ^[^|]*\|word2\|
    ^[^|]*\|word3\|
    [...]
   ```

   and in addition, `fgrep -f` was replaced by `grep -E -f` for these methods.

### Running the tests

Here is the script used for running all the tests. It uses the Bash `time` command to record the time spent for each script. Note that the `time` command returns three different times call `real`, `user`, and `sys`. First I used `user` + `sys`, but realized that this was incorrect when using Gnu parallel command, so the time reported below is now the `real` part returned by `time`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/556405/2173773) for more information about the different times returned by `time`.

The first test is run with `file1.txt` containing 5 lines, and `file2.txt` containing `1000000` lines. Here is the first 52 lines of the `run_all.pl` script, the rest of the script is available [here](https://github.com/hakonhagland/fast-grep-bench/blob/master/run_all.pl).

**run_all.pl**

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Cwd;
use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Printer;
use FGB::Common;
use List::Util qw(max shuffle);
use Number::Bytes::Human qw(format_bytes);
use Sys::Info;

GetOptions (
    "verbose"       => \my $verbose,
    "check"         => \my $check,
    "single-case=s" => \my $case,
    "expected=i"    => \my $expected_no_lines,
) or die("Error in command line arguments\n");

my $test_dir    = 'solutions';
my $output_file = 'out.txt';
my $wc_expected = $expected_no_lines; # expected number of output lines

my $tests       = get_test_names( $test_dir, $case );

my $file2_size  = get_file2_size();
my $num_cpus    = Sys::Info->new()->device( CPU => () )->count;

chdir $test_dir;
my $cmd = 'run.sh';
my @times;
for my $case (@$tests) {
    my $savedir = getcwd();
    chdir $case;
    say "Running '$case'..";
    my $arg = get_cmd_args( $case, $file2_size, $num_cpus );
    my $output = `bash -c "{ time -p $cmd $arg; } 2>&1"`;
    my ($user, $sys, $real ) = get_run_times( $output );
    print_timings( $user, $sys, $real ) if $verbose;
    check_output_is_ok( $output_file, $wc_expected, $verbose, $check );
    print "\n" if $verbose;
    push @times, $real;
    #push @times, $user + $sys; # this is wrong when using Gnu parallel
    chdir $savedir;
}

say "Done.\n";

print_summary( $tests, \@times );
```

### Results

Here is the output from running the tests:

```
$  run_all.pl --verbose
Running 'inian3'..
..finished in 0.45 seconds ( user: 0.44, sys: 0.00 )
..no of output lines: 66711

Running 'inian2'..
..finished in 0.73 seconds ( user: 0.73, sys: 0.00 )
..no of output lines: 66711

Running 'Vasiliou'..
..finished in 0.09 seconds ( user: 0.08, sys: 0.00 )
..no of output lines: 66711

Running 'codeforester_orig'..
..finished in 0.05 seconds ( user: 0.05, sys: 0.00 )
..no of output lines: 66711

Running 'codeforester'..
..finished in 0.45 seconds ( user: 0.44, sys: 0.01 )
..no of output lines: 66711

[...]
```

### Summary

[Results obtained by @Vasiliou are shown in the middle column.]

```
                               |Vasiliou
My Benchmark                   |Results  |   Details
-------------------------------|---------|----------------------
inian4             : 0.04s     |0.22s    | LC_ALL fgrep -f [loose] 
codeforester_orig  : 0.05s     |         | fgrep -f [loose]
Vasiliou2          : 0.06s     |0.16s    | [LC_ALL join [requires sorted files]]
BOC1               : 0.06s     |         | grep -E [loose] 
BOC2               : 0.07s     |15s      | LC_ALL grep -E [loose] 
BOC2B              : 0.07s     |         | LC_ALL grep -E [strict] 
inian4B            : 0.08s     |         | LC_ALL grep -E -f [strict] 
Vasiliou           : 0.08s     |0.23s    | [join [requires sorted files]] 
gregory1B          : 0.08s     |         | [parallel + grep -E -f [strict]] 
ikegami            : 0.1s      |         | grep -P 
gregory1           : 0.11s     |0.5s     | [parallel + fgrep -f [loose]] 
hakon1             : 0.14s     |         | [perl + c]
BOC1B              : 0.14s     |         | grep -E [strict] 
jjoao              : 0.21s     |         | [compiled flex generated c code] 
inian6             : 0.26s     |0.7s     | [LC_ALL awk + split+dict] 
codeforester_origB : 0.28s     |         | grep -E -f [strict] 
dawg               : 0.35s     |         | [python + split+dict] 
inian3             : 0.44s     |1.1s     | [awk + split+dict] 
zdim2              : 0.4s      |         | [perl + split+dict] 
codeforester       : 0.45s     |         | [perl + split+dict] 
oliv               : 0.5s      |         | [python + compiled regex + re.search()] 
zdim               : 0.61s     |         | [perl + regexp+dict] 
inian2             : 0.73s     |1.7s     | [awk + index($0,i)] 
inian5             : 18.12s    |         | [LC_ALL awk + match($0,i) [loose]] 
inian1             : 19.46s    |         | [awk + match($0,i) [loose]] 
inian5B            : 42.27s    |         | [LC_ALL awk + match($0,i) [strict]] 
inian1B            : 85.67s    |         | [awk + match($0,i) [strict]] 

Vasiliou Results : 2 X CPU Intel 2 Duo T6570 @ 2.10GHz - 2Gb RAM-Debian Testing 64bit- kernel 4.9.0.1 - no cpu freq scaling.
```

### A more realistic test case

I then created a more realistic case with `file1.txt` having 100 words and `file2.txt` having 10 million lines (268Mb file size). I extracted 1000 random words from the dictionary at `/usr/share/dict/american-english` using `shuf -n1000 /usr/share/dict/american-english > words.txt` then extracted 100 of these words into `file1.txt` and then constructed `file2.txt` the same way as described above for the first test case. Note that the dictionary file was UTF-8 encoded, and I stripped away all non-ASCII characters from the `words.txt`.

Then I run the test without the three slowest methods from the previous case. I.e. `inian1`, `inian2`, and `inian5` were left out. Here are the new results:

```
gregory1           : 0.86s     | [parallel + fgrep -f [loose]]
Vasiliou2          : 0.94s     | [LC_ALL join [requires sorted files]]
inian4B            : 1.12s     | LC_ALL grep -E -f [strict] 
BOC2B              : 1.13s     | LC_ALL grep -E [strict] 
BOC2               : 1.15s     | LC_ALL grep -E [loose] 
BOC1               : 1.18s     | grep -E [loose] 
ikegami            : 1.33s     | grep -P 
Vasiliou           : 1.37s     | [join [requires sorted files]]
hakon1             : 1.44s     | [perl + c]
inian4             : 2.18s     | LC_ALL fgrep -f [loose] 
codeforester_orig  : 2.2s      | fgrep -f [loose] 
inian6             : 2.82s     | [LC_ALL awk + split+dict] 
jjoao              : 3.09s     | [compiled flex generated c code] 
dawg               : 3.54s     | [python + split+dict] 
zdim2              : 4.21s     | [perl + split+dict]
codeforester       : 4.67s     | [perl + split+dict] 
inian3             : 5.52s     | [awk + split+dict] 
zdim               : 6.55s     | [perl + regexp+dict] 
gregory1B          : 45.36s    | [parallel + grep -E -f [strict]] 
oliv               : 60.35s    | [python + compiled regex + re.search()] 
BOC1B              : 74.71s    | grep -E [strict] 
codeforester_origB : 75.52s    | grep -E -f [strict]
```

#### Note

The `grep` based solutions were looking for a match on the whole line, so in this case they contained some false matches: the methods `codeforester_orig`, `BOC1`, `BOC2`, `gregory1`, `inian4`, and `oliv` extracted 1,087,609 lines out of 10,000,000 lines, whereas the other methods extracted the correct 997,993 lines from `file2.txt`.

### Notes

- I tested this on my Ubuntu 16.10 laptop (Intel Core i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz)
- The whole benchmark study is available [here](https://github.com/hakonhagland/fast-grep-bench).

Comment: Nice testing. I'm surprised that Join solution could achieve good results.  Also notice that join solution should require sort before to work - Please re-check. Moreover i think that you missed codeforester accepted solution (perl code) , and is quite strange that zdim perl solution is much slower than grep while OP claims the opposite (and we tend to believe him :) )

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Thanks for the comments! I was also a bit surprised over the results. Note that `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` are in fact sorted. I uploaded everything to GitHub [here](https://github.com/hakonhagland/fast-grep-bench). Please try run the code on your machine and report back. Just do `git clone https://github.com/hakonhagland/fast-grep-bench.git` and then run `run_case.sh 75w-5w-1Mw` to run exactly the same case as I did :)

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Updated answer to include the accepted Perl solution by codeforester. Sorry I forgot it.

Comment: Make sure your input contains things you do not want to match. For example if you ONLY want to do exact string matches on the 2nd field of file2, then include `foo` and `f.*o` in file1 plus `a|foobar|b` and `foo|a|b` in file2 and so on. It's always trivial to write tools that match on the things you do want but then harder to exclude the things you don't want so the only way to really test a solution is to put effort into creating test cases that include the things you could imagine might match but should not (typically partial, regexp, or wrong-part-of-line matches).

Comment: I downloaded your small files (file1 5 words - file2 1M lines)and i run some of the solutions directly. Some results: 1.`Inian3 C localle awk hash - time 0.7 secs - 1.1 secs without C locale` -2. `Inian4 - C localle fgrep , time 0.22 secs` -3. `gregory1 parallel, time 0.5 secs` -4. `BOC2 grep -E wih C localle , time 15 sec` - 5. `inian2 - awk index , time 1.7 sec` -6.`join solution without sorting 0.23 secs`. All results redirected to file3.txt - matches were 66711 for all cases. 2 X CPU Intel 2 Duo T6570 @ 2.10GHz - 2Gb RAM-Debian Testing 64bit- kernel 4.9.0.1 - no cpu freq scaling.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Thanks for the results! One question: `BOC2 15s` should it be 1.5s or 0.15s instead of 15s?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Updated answer with your results, and added `inian6` method (same as `inian3` but with `LC_ALL=C`). Thanks for the suggestion,  it seems `inian6` is siginificantly faster than `inian3`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland For BOC2 , i did the test several times and it was 15 seconds indeed. It is not a typo error. I don't know why `fgrep -F` is fast as hell and `grep -E` is that slow. Same conditions, same machine. I can not explain it.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Since this post tends to become a future benchmark reference, i would suggest to include in your main answer the direct location of the RAW file1 and file2.txt (both small files and large files). I had to search a lot in your github to locate the correct files to wget them. By providing raw links , anybody can wget the files and make a simple test with `time` (no need to get your whole comparison script). I did all tests using `# time <solution>` - for example `# time LC_ALL=C fgrep -F -f file1.txt file2.txt >file3.txt`

Comment: One last comment to it whom it may concern: has been proved in one of my small amateur projects[1] that grep can be 100% faster  by disabling the cpu frequency scaling. In some machines (like one of mine) cpu freq scaling is enabled by default with `powersave` options.  By changing cpu scaling to "performace" or by manually applying max cpu freq regular grep finished the job in 50% less time than previous "powersave" governor. @codeforester you might also want to check this in your machine. [1]: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146383/optimize-text-search-in-files-with-bash

Comment: I wish you'd included regexp metacharacters in file1 so we could filter out solutions that use regexp instead of string comparisons. Also do you know if any of the words from file1 were partial matches for words in field2 of file2 (e.g. `foo` vs `foobar`)? You should have some of those to again filter out non-solutions. Finally - did you do 3rd-iteration timing to remove the effects of cacheing?

Comment: Half of the solutions you benchmarked don't even work! The following fail to handle `file1.txt` `foo1` `file2.txt` `date1|foo12|number5`: BOC1, BOC2, codeforester_orig, gregory1, inian2, inian4, oliv

Comment: Nice how fixing `gregory1` changed it from the slowest solution to the fastest solution that works!

Comment: Did you adjust for those solutions that `print` vs those that write to a file? Printing can be a substantial IO penalty. For an apples to apples comparison, they should all print or all write to a file...

Comment: @dawg Yes I pretty confident that I did that :) You can check how the methods are implemented [here](https://github.com/hakonhagland/fast-grep-bench/tree/master/solutions). All methods are being run either directly or indirectly through the shell script `run.sh` in the pertinent subfolder of [solutions](https://github.com/hakonhagland/fast-grep-bench/tree/master/solutions). So for example, your python script is being run using `run.py >out.txt`, where `run.py` is the Python script.

Comment: ... In fact the tests should not work if they printed to `STDOUT` instead
of to file, since I later (after the method has been run) read their
output file to check if they extracted the right number of lines from
`file2.txt`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland, very cool (+1). I know that this question is "old" but I could not resist :-) .  Could you time my answer just for curiosity? (I know I am not a wining candidate)

Comment: @jjoao This topic has so many info gathered together that everytime i see a grep question in SE i point people here... These solutions with benchmarks should be a "grep like" wiki!

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou, I "came" to this question because I saw a link posted by you :) ...

Comment: @JJoao That is Cool! :-)))

Comment: At small files test, my solution achieved 0.23 seconds in my machine. I was able to reduce in my machine time down to 0.16 seconds just by applying `LC_ALL=C` in front of join... Do you want to give a try with your files to verify if there is a performance increase with C locale?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Thanks! I have updated my answer. This was really impressive :)

Comment: Newer versions of `parallel` will compute the block size if you give it a negative number: `--block-size -1` = one chuck per jobslot, `-2` = two chunks per jobslot.

Answer (score 9):

Did you try `Awk` that could speed up things a bit:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{hash[$1]; next}{for (i in hash) if (match($0,i)) {print; break}}' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt
```

(or) using `index()` function in `Awk` as suggested by comments from [Benjamin W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w), below

```
awk 'FNR==NR{hash[$1]; next}{for (i in hash) if (index($0,i)) {print; break}}' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt
```

(or) a more direct regex match as suggested by [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) in comments,

```
awk 'FNR==NR{hash[$1]; next}{for (i in hash) if ($0~i) {print; break}}' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt
```

is all you need. I'm guessing this will be faster but not exactly sure on files with million+ entries. Here the problem is with the possibility match in anywhere along the line. Had the same been in any particular column (e.g. say `$2` alone), a faster approach could be

```
awk 'FNR==NR{hash[$1]; next}$2 in hash' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt
```

---

Also you could speed-things up by playing with the `locale` set in your system. Paraphrasing from this wonderful [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/112235) on the subject, you could speed up things pretty quickly by setting passing the locale `LC_ALL=C` to the command *locally* being run.

On any `GNU` based system, the defaults for the `locale`

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

With one variable `LC_ALL`, you can set all `LC_` type variables at once to a specified locale

```
$ LC_ALL=C locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"       
LC_ALL=C
```

> So what does this impact?

Simply put, when using the `locale C` it will default to the server's base Unix/Linux language of `ASCII`. Basically when you `grep` something, by default your locale is going to be internationalized and set to `UTF-8`, which can represent every character in the Unicode character set to help display any of the world's writing systems, currently over more than `110,000` unique characters, whereas with `ASCII` each character is encoded in a single byte sequence and its character set comprises of no longer than `128` unique characters.

So it translates to this, when using `grep` on a file encoded in `UTF-8` character-set, it needs to match each character with any of the hundred thousand unique characters, but just `128` in `ASCII`, so use your `fgrep` as

```
LC_ALL=C fgrep -F -f file1.txt file2.txt
```

Also, the same can be adapted to the `Awk`, since it uses a `regex` match with the `match($0,i)` call, setting the `C` locale could speed up the string match.

```
LC_ALL=C awk 'FNR==NR{hash[$1]; next}{for (i in hash) if (match($0,i)) {print; break}}' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt
```

Comment: The note about locale is really good. I don't know if it works (I suppose yes), but simply having thought about it is worth.

Comment: `index` might be faster than `match`.

Comment: @Inian - thank you for your effort.  I ran your `awk` code and it terminated with an error after 55 minutes.  I realized that the big file has nulls in column2 and awk didn't like it.  It produced 40K matches - I expected 126K matches for the 1.3M lines in big file.  Obviously, 55 minutes is too much, that too for the partial job.  I feel `awk` is simply not suited for file sizes like this.

Comment: @codeforester: Thanks for trying the same, `big file has nulls in column2` is a new requirement, I can modify the answer for it. But on a billion line file, no shell tool can scale smoothly. Did you try the `fgrep` with `LC_ALL=C` locale? And can you let me know whhich one you tried? I had multiple solutions with `match()`, `index()`

Comment: Thanks @Inian.  I shall try that one as well.  I am going to publish the detailed results before the bounty closes.

Comment: @codeforester: Do try anything except this `awk 'FNR==NR{hash[$1]; next}$2 in hash' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt`

Comment: @codeforester: Is there a reason for why this was down-vote?

Comment: @Inian - I down voted because the `awk` solution is definitely unsuitable for this requirement.  I knew `awk` is generally not good when big files are involved, and this example kind of settled it.  I also down voted the python solution and left a comment for the Perl solution.

Comment: @codeforester: To be honest, there is no definitive answer for the question. People can only do code-golf ( the best among the other answers using least resources), I did my best to solve it, as the OP your feedback of downvoting is not a healthy approach here as there is no 100% solution for this. Do appreciate people for the time they are spending to answer your problem.

Comment: And claiming `Awk is not good for big files` is not correct. see https://lyness.io/the-functional-and-performance-differences-of-sed-awk-and-other-unix-parsing-utilities

Comment: @codeforester: Appreciate your feedback, any requirement if you have.

Comment: @codeforester wrt `awk solution is definitely unsuitable for this requirement. I knew awk is generally not good when big files are involved,` - what are you talking about? Awk is well suited for your question and is excellent when big files are involved since it's designed and highly optimized to ONLY to text manipulation.

Comment: @Inian `awk 'FNR==NR{hash[$1]; next}$2 in hash' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt` is **THE** awk solution for a full string match on field2. Where you wrote `match(i,$0)` ITYM `match($0,i)` but that's needlessly calling a function (and populating RSTART and RLENGTH) vs just `$0~i`. The match() and index() versions wouldn't be useful anyway though as awk is splitting each line of file2 into fields and so cannot be faster than `grep` or `grep -F` for a regexp or string partial match on the whole line.

Comment: @EdMorton: As ever incorporated your valuable comments.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for chiming in.  I wonder why `awk` is so slow in this case.  The Perl script took just a few seconds and `awk` didn't complete in several hours.

Comment: @codeforester please don't say `awk is so slow`, etc. - its a specific script you ran that was slow. What was that script? There is no way that the right awk script (`'FNR==NR{hash[$1]; next}$2 in hash'`) would take more than a few seconds for the task you described. Also did your input contain the rainy day cases I suggested so you can tell if the 2 scripts handle those correctly? I mean I have no idea since idk which scripts you ran but the perl script might be fast because it doesn't actually handle rainy day cases.

Comment: @EdMorton: I stand corrected.  @Inian's solution `awk 'FNR==NR{hash[$1]; next}$2 in hash' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt` did finish in 40 seconds and that is quite impressive.

Comment: @codeforester: Appreciate you awarding me the bounty, hope the answer was quite helpful to you.

Answer (score 6):

Assumptions: 1. You want to run this search on just your local workstation. 2. Your have multiple cores/cpus to take advantage of a parallel search.

```
parallel --pipepart -a file2.txt --block 10M fgrep -F -f file1.txt
```

Some further tweaks depending on the context: 
A. Disable NLS with LANG=C (this is mentioned already in another answer)
B. Set a max number of matches with the -m flag.

Note: I'm guessing that file2 is ~4GB and the 10M block size is ok, but you may need to optimize the block size to get the fastest run.

Comment: If the files are bigger: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Grepping-n-lines-for-m-regular-expressions

Answer (score 4):

This Perl script (`a`) generates a regex pattern:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Regexp::Assemble qw( );

chomp( my @ids = <> );
my $ra = Regexp::Assemble->new();
$ra->add(quotemeta($_)) for @ids;
print("^[^|]*\\|(?:" . (re::regexp_pattern($ra->re()))[0] . ")\\|");
```

Here's how it can be used:

```
$ LC_ALL=C grep -P "$( a file1.txt )" file2.txt
date1|foo1|number1
date2|foo2|number2
date1|bar1|number1
date2|bar2|number2
```

Note the the script uses Regexp::Assemble, so you may need to install it.

```
sudo su
cpan Regexp::Assemble
```

Notes:

- Unlike the solutions dubbed BOC1, BOC2, codeforester_orig, gregory1, inian2, inian4 and oliv, my solution correctly handles

  ```
  file1.txt
  foo1

  file2.txt
  date1|foo12|number5
  ```
- Mine should be better than the similar [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42346955/589924) by @BOC because the pattern is optimized to reduce backtracking. (Mine also works if there are more than three fields in `file2.txt`, whereas the linked solution can fail.)
- I don't know how it compares to the split+dictionary solutions.

Comment: I interpreted the OP's question as: *"second field (of file2.txt) should be equal to one of the words in file1.txt"*. If so, we have a match. So then you are right, many of the solutions can give wrong results. I also mentioned that in my answer: For the large test case in my answer, many of the methods indeed gave false matches.

Comment: Maybe we should change `file1.txt` for the methods that give false matches to for example `^[^|]*\|foo1\|`? Then they should give correct results (provided their command is changed to `grep -E -f` instead of using `fgrep`) according to the assumed specifications of the OP. And the comparison between the methods would become less confusing :)

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, Curious as to why you didn't add this to your benchmark when you made the other recent addition. Is it because you don't have R::A? I'm curious how it compares to BOC's i.e. how much the groupings from R::A helps.

Answer (score 4):

Here is Perl solution that uses [`Inline::C`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Inline-C/lib/Inline/C.pod) to speed up the search for matching fields in the large file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Inline C => './search.c';

my $smallfile = 'file1.txt';
my $bigfile   = 'file2.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $smallfile or die "Can't open $smallfile: $!";
my %word = map { chomp; $_ => 1 } <$fh>;
search( $bigfile, \%word );
```

The `search()` sub routine is implemented in pure C using [`perlapi`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html) to look up keys in the small file dictionary `%words`:

**search.c**:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>


#define BLOCK_SIZE 8192       /* how much to read from file each time */
static char read_buf[BLOCK_SIZE + 1];

/*  reads a block from file, returns -1 on error, 0 on EOF, 
     else returns chars read, pointer to buf, and pointer to end of buf  */
size_t read_block( int fd, char **ret_buf, char **end_buf ) {
    int ret;
    char *buf = read_buf;
    size_t len = BLOCK_SIZE;
    while (len != 0 && (ret = read(fd, buf, len)) != 0) {
        if (ret == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            perror( "read" );
            return ret;
        }
        len -= ret;
        buf += ret;
    }
    *end_buf = buf;
    *ret_buf = read_buf;
    return (size_t) (*end_buf - *ret_buf);
}

/* updates the line buffer with the char pointed to by cur,
   also updates cur
    */
int update_line_buffer( char **cur, char **line, size_t *llen, size_t max_line_len ) {
    if ( *llen > max_line_len ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Too long line. Maximimum allowed line length is %ld\n",
                 max_line_len );
        return 0;
    }
    **line = **cur;
    (*line)++;
    (*llen)++;
    (*cur)++; 
    return 1;
}


/*    search for first pipe on a line (or next line if this is empty),
    assume line ptr points to beginning of line buffer.
  return 1 on success
  Return 0 if pipe could not be found for some reason, or if 
    line buffer length was exceeded  */
int search_field_start(
    int fd, char **cur, char **end_buf, char **line, size_t *llen, size_t max_line_len
) {
    char *line_start = *line;

    while (1) {
        if ( *cur >= *end_buf ) {
            size_t res = read_block( fd, cur, end_buf );        
            if (res <= 0) return 0;
        }
        if ( **cur == '|' ) break;
        /* Currently we just ignore malformed lines ( lines that do not have a pipe,
           and empty lines in the input */
        if ( **cur == '\n' ) {
            *line = line_start;
            *llen = 0;
            (*cur)++;
        }
        else {
            if (! update_line_buffer( cur, line, llen, max_line_len ) ) return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

/* assume cur points at starting pipe of field
  return -1 on read error, 
  return 0 if field len was too large for buffer or line buffer length exceed,
  else return 1
  and field, and  length of field
 */
int copy_field(
    int fd, char **cur, char **end_buf, char *field,
    size_t *flen, char **line, size_t *llen, size_t max_field_len, size_t max_line_len
) {
    *flen = 0;
    while( 1 ) {
        if (! update_line_buffer( cur, line, llen, max_line_len ) ) return 0;
        if ( *cur >= *end_buf ) {
            size_t res = read_block( fd, cur, end_buf );        
            if (res <= 0) return -1;
        }
        if ( **cur == '|' ) break;
        if ( *flen > max_field_len ) {
            printf( "Field width too large. Maximum allowed field width: %ld\n",
                    max_field_len );
            return 0;
        }
        *field++ = **cur;
        (*flen)++;
    }
    /* It is really not necessary to null-terminate the field 
       since we return length of field and also field could 
       contain internal null characters as well
    */
    //*field = '\0';
    return 1;
}

/* search to beginning of next line,
  return 0 on error,
  else return 1 */
int search_eol(
    int fd, char **cur, char **end_buf, char **line, size_t *llen, size_t max_line_len)
{
    while (1) {
        if ( *cur >= *end_buf ) {
            size_t res = read_block( fd, cur, end_buf );        
            if (res <= 0) return 0;
        }
        if ( !update_line_buffer( cur, line, llen, max_line_len ) ) return 0;
        if ( *(*cur-1) == '\n' ) {
            break;
        }
    }
    //**line = '\0'; // not necessary
    return 1;
}

#define MAX_FIELD_LEN 80  /* max number of characters allowed in a field  */
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 80   /* max number of characters allowed on a line */

/* 
   Get next field ( i.e. field #2 on a line). Fields are
   separated by pipes '|' in the input file.
   Also get the line of the field.
   Return 0 on error,
   on success: Move internal pointer to beginning of next line
     return 1 and the field.
 */
size_t get_field_and_line_fast(
    int fd, char *field, size_t *flen, char *line, size_t *llen
) {
    static char *cur = NULL;
    static char *end_buf = NULL;

    size_t res;
    if (cur == NULL) {
        res = read_block( fd, &cur, &end_buf );        
        if ( res <= 0 ) return 0;
    }
    *llen = 0;
    if ( !search_field_start( fd, &cur, &end_buf, &line, llen, MAX_LINE_LEN )) return 0;
    if ( (res = copy_field(
        fd, &cur, &end_buf, field, flen, &line, llen, MAX_FIELD_LEN, MAX_LINE_LEN
    ) ) <= 0)
        return 0;
    if ( !search_eol( fd, &cur, &end_buf, &line, llen, MAX_LINE_LEN ) ) return 0;
    return 1;
}

void search( char *filename, SV *href) 
{
    if( !SvROK( href ) || ( SvTYPE( SvRV( href ) ) != SVt_PVHV ) ) {
        croak( "Not a hash reference" );
    }

    int fd = open (filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        croak( "Could not open file '%s'", filename );
    }
    char field[MAX_FIELD_LEN+1];
    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN+1];
    size_t flen, llen;
    HV *hash = (HV *)SvRV( href );
    while ( get_field_and_line_fast( fd, field, &flen, line, &llen ) ) {
        if( hv_exists( hash, field, flen ) )
            fwrite( line, sizeof(char), llen, stdout);
    }
    if (close(fd) == -1)
        croak( "Close failed" );

}
```

Tests indicate that it is approximately 3 times faster than the fastest pure Perl solution (see method `zdim2` in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42370477/2173773)) presented here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Python solution using sets -- roughly equivalent to a Perl key only hash or awk array in concept.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys 

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    tgt={e.rstrip() for e in f}

with open(sys.argv[2]) as f:
    for line in f:
        cells=line.split("|")
        if cells[1] in tgt:
            print line.rstrip()
```

When I run this on files of similar size, it runs in about 8 seconds.

Same speed as:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1]; next} $2 in arr{print $0}' FS="|" /tmp/f1 /tmp/f2
```

Both the Python and awk solution here are full string match only; not a partial regex style match.

Since the awk solution is fast and POSIX compliant, that is the better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Can you give a try to `join`? Files must be sorted though...

```
$ cat d.txt
bar1
bar2
foo1
foo2

$ cat e.txt
date1|bar1|number1
date2|bar2|number2
date3|bar3|number3
date1|foo1|number1
date2|foo2|number2
date3|foo3|number3

$ join --nocheck-order -11 -22 -t'|' -o 2.1 2.2 2.3 d.txt e.txt
date1|bar1|number1
date2|bar2|number2
date1|foo1|number1
date2|foo2|number2
```

Small Update:
By using LC_ALL=C in front of join, things are really speed up as can be seen in the benchmark of [Håkon Hægland](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-text-file-from-another-larger-text-file-in-bash/42370477#42370477)

PS1: I have my doubts if join can be faster than grep -f ...

Comment: @codeforester Obviously this solution is only vaild with your previous version of the question : pattern in file 1 to match field 2 of file 2. It would be interesting to see the timing results also, even if we compare only the seconf field.

Answer (score 2):

Though this thread is over, but all grep-alike methods between two files are gathered in this post, why not to add this awk alternative, similar (or even improved) to the bounty winning Inian's awk solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}a[$2]' patterns.txt FS="|" datafile.txt >matches.txt # For matches restricted on Field2 of datafile
```

This is equivalent to Inian awk `$2 in hash` solution but it could be even faster due to the fact that we don't ask awk to check if the whole hash array contains $2 of file2 - we just check if a[$2] has a value or not.

While reading the first patterns file appart from creating the hash array we assign also a value.

If `$2` of datafile had been found before in patterns file, then `a[$2]` would have a value and thus will be printed because is not null.

if `a[$2]` of datafile returns no value(null) this is translated to false => no printing.

Extension to match any of the three fields of datafile:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}(a[$1] || a[$2] || a[$3])' patterns.txt FS="|" datafile.txt >matches.txt. #Printed if any of the three fields of datafile match pattern.
```

In both cases, applying **LC_ALL=C** in front of awk, seems to speed things up.

PS1: Offcourse this solution has also the pitfalls of all awk solutions. Is not a pattern matching. Is a direct / fixed matching between of the two files, like most of the solutions inhere.

PS2: In my poor machine benchmark using the small benchmark files of [Håkon Hægland](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-text-file-from-another-larger-text-file-in-bash/42370477#42370477), i get about 20% better performance comparing to the `awk 'FNR==NR{hash[$1]; next}$2 in hash' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt`

Comment: @HåkonHægland  - Would you mind to benchmark this solution as well , using your small and big files?

Comment: Hi George! Thanks for the input. My first impression is that `$2 in a` should be equivalent to `a[$2]`. But maybe I am wrong, I do not know all details of awk inner workings. But I believe both requires a hash lookup.. and therefore same speed

Comment: I tested it now and the speed seems to be the same as for `inian3` in my comparison answer. So this could indicate that the methods are indeed equivalent. What do you think?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Hi! Ok, good to know.So we can't claim that this method is faster. In my old machine , it seems that gave better results than inian3. I will re-check. Did you try also with C localle?

Answer (score 1):

A possible way is to use `python`:

```
$ cat test.py
import sys,re

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f1:
    patterns = f1.read().splitlines() # read pattern from file1 without the trailing newline

m = re.compile("|".join(patterns))    # create the regex

with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as f2:
    for line in f2: 
        if m.search(line) : 
            print line,               # print line from file2 if this one matches the regex
```

and use it like this:

```
python test.py file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: Why do we need to create the huge regex from patterns array?

Comment: I ran this over a 1.3M lines file2.txt.  It has been running for more than 3.5 hours and so far has produced 86K results (of the 126K expected matches).  Definitely not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Perl for this:

*Please note that this will hog memory and your machine/server better has some.*

**Sample Data:**

```
%_STATION@gaurav * /root/ga/pl> head file1.txt file2.txt
==> file1.txt <==
foo1
foo2
...
bar1
bar2
...

==> file2.txt <==
date1|foo1|number1
date2|foo2|number2
date3|foo3|number3
...
date1|bar1|number1
date2|bar2|number2
date3|bar3|number3
%_STATION@gaurav * /root/ga/study/pl>
```

**Script Output:** Script will produce **final** output  in a file named `output_comp`.

```
%_STATION@gaurav * /root/ga/pl> ./comp.pl  file1.txt file2.txt ; cat output_comp
date1|bar1|number1
date2|bar2|number2
date2|foo2|number2
date1|foo1|number1
%_STATION@gaurav * /root/ga/pl>
```

**Script:**

```
%_STATION@gaurav * /root/ga/pl> cat comp.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;
use Data::Dumper ;

my ($file1,$file2) = @ARGV ;
my $output = "output_comp" ;
my %hash ;    # This will store main comparison data.
my %tmp ;     # This will store already selected results, to be skipped.
(scalar @ARGV != 2 ? (print "Need 2 files!\n") : ()) ? exit 1 : () ;

# Read all files at once and use their name as the key.
for (@ARGV) {
  open FH, "<$_" or die "Cannot open $_\n" ;
  while  (my $line = <FH>) {chomp $line ;$hash{$_}{$line} = "$line"}
  close FH ;
}

# Now we churn through the data and compare to generate
# the sorted output in the output file.
open FH, ">>$output" or die "Cannot open outfile!\n" ;
foreach my $k1 (keys %{$hash{$file1}}){
  foreach my $k2 (keys %{$hash{$file2}}){
    if ($k1 =~ m/^.+?$k2.+?$/) {
      if (!defined $tmp{"$hash{$file2}{$k2}"}) {
        print FH "$hash{$file2}{$k2}\n" ;
        $tmp{"$hash{$file2}{$k2}"} = 1 ;
      }
    }
  }
}
close FH  ;
%_STATION@gaurav * /root/ga/pl>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are almost on the right track!  There is no need to load the second (bigger) file into the hash.  Please see my solution below.

Comment: Yes, You are right. Could have done that, actually should have done that but anyways, how much time did this one take?

Comment: I didn't run it since I knew it is not at all optimal because of the memory consumption.  The `fgrep` command earlier had made my MPB's fan go crazy and hence didn't have the courage to try this one!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, grep is a good tool highly optimised for huge file2.txt but maybe not for so many patterns to search. I suggest to combine all the strings of file1.txt into a single huge regexp like \|bar1|bar2|foo1|foo2\|

```
echo  '\|'$(paste -s -d '|' file1.txt)'\|' > regexp1.txt

grep -E -f regexp1.txt file2.txt > file.matched
```

And of course LANG=C may help.
Please give feedback or send your files so I can test myself.

Answer (score 1):

I would use SQLite3 :) Maybe in-memory database or whatever. Import the files and use SQL query.

Comment: That may be a good idea.  I wanted a simple command line solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using **flex**:

#### 1: build the flex processor:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{ printf "%%%%\n\n.*\\|(%s",$0 } 
            { printf "|%s",$0 } 
       END  { print ")\\|.*\\n ECHO;\n.*\\n ;\n%%\n" }' file1.txt > a.fl
```

#### 2: compile it

```
$ flex -Ca -F a.fl ; cc -O lex.yy.c -lfl
```

#### 3: and run

```
$ a.out < file2.txt  > out
```

Compiling (cc ...) is a slow process; this approach will pay just for cases
of stable file1.txt

(In my machine) The times taken to run a search "100 in 10_000_000" test in this approach is 3 times faster than `LC_ALL=C fgrep...`

Comment: Hi JJoao. Thanks for the input! I updated my answer to include this method also.

Comment: @HåkonHægland, thank you; The comparison between this approach and the others is still difficult for me (flex for very big expressions and the compilation often take a lot of time) . Could you give-me the time of the final "run" ? ( `a.out < file2.txt  > out`)

Comment: If you are wondering if the compilation time is included in the results I presented: It is not. I mentioned that in the beginning of the question, where I describe the different methods. I am not familiar with `flex` so I cannot tell if 38s is to be expected or not for the large case, or if something else is wrong (that causes the method to take so long time).

Comment: @HåkonHægland, sorry to all the trouble I am giving you. I am surprised about the 38 s -- that is why I like benchmarks!  I am going to study it.

Comment: @HåkonHægland, Sorry again: I was generating the wrong flex code. Updated -- this time I believe it will be 10 times faster.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my answer to use the new `a.fl` files. It looks much better now :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland, and thank you again for your patience... ( the influence of  optimizers `flex -F` and `cc -O` was bigger than I expected)

Answer (score 0):

setting language etc helps a little, perhaps.

otherwise I can not think of a magic solution to escape from your basic issue:
the data is not structured, so you will have a search 
that comes down to the number of lines in file1 multiplied with the number of lines in file2.

put the billion lines in a database, and index it in a smart way, is the only speed up I can think of. that index would have to be very smart, though......

SImple solution is: have enough memory to fit everything in to.
otherwise nothing much more you can do about this....