# Match patterns from one file awk not working

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

I want to match strings from a pattern file to look into Source.txt file.

pattern_list.txt has 139k lines

Source.txt more than 5 millions lines

If I use grep like this it tooks 2 seconds to get the output.

```
grep -F -f pattern_list.txt Source.txt > Output.txt
```

But if I try with this AWK script it gets stuck and after 10 min I need to stop because nothing happens.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} {

for (i in a) if ($0 ~ i) print $0

 }' FS=, OFS=, pattern_list.txt Source.txt > Output.txt
```

pattern_list is like this

```
21051
99888
95746
```

and source.txt like this

```
72300,2,694
21051,1,694
63143,3,694
25223,2,694
99888,8,694
53919,2,694
51059,2,694
```

What it wrong with my AWK script?

I'm running on Cygwin in Windows.

Comment: Another approach: `join -t "," <(sort pattern_list) <(sort source.txt)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to find lines of a file from another larger file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-file-from-another-larger-file-in-bash)

Comment: @codeforester Hi, I was asking more about why my awk script was so slow, than that ask the fastest way to do it in perl, grep, bash or other tools.

Comment: Since your `awk` code is trying to exactly what the accepted answer in the linked post is doing, I considered it a duplicate, or at least, related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are doing literal match this should be faster than your approach

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} $1 in a{print $1,$3,$8,$20}' pattern_list source > output
```

However, I think `sort/join` will still be faster than grep and awk.

Comment: Excellent. Now the execution time with your awk script is less than 4 seconds. But since my original source file has several fields how to say in your script that print only $3, $8 and $20 for the matched strings?

Comment: Can't improve on karakfa's answer, but for grep vs awk performance tests see https://www.polydesmida.info/BASHing/2018-10-24.html

Comment: @karakfa Thanks a lot. It works exactly as I wanted.

Comment: @user2138595 Thanks for share the info. Yes, is what I understood in theory and practice, that awk is champion in speed.

Answer (score 2):

If increasing performance is your goal, you'll need to multithread this (AWK is unlikely faster, perhaps slower?).

If I were you, I'd partition the source file, then search each part:

```
$ split -l 100000 src.txt src_part
$ ls src_part* | xargs -n1 -P4 fgrep -f pat.txt > matches.txt
$ rm src_part*
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but what I know is that awk is faster than grep. So, I don't know what happens here.

Comment: @GerCas I doubt that is true as AWK has to parse the script, then run. grep, on the other hand, is heavily optimized for its purpose.